# How to format a date in a Laravel Blade?

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

This Laravel Blade code line make view in the browser

```
<td>{!! $job->created_at->format('d M Y, G:i') !!}</td>
<td>{!! $job->deleted_at->format('d M Y, G:i') !!}</td>
```

as

```
"10 Jan 2018, 9:08"    
"10 Jan 2018, 13:08"
```

How to adjust CSS as below time data?

```
"10 Jan 2018,  9:08"
"10 Jan 2018, 13:08"
```

add... I don't want just insert '0' into time data as below, but insert blank should be a answer when time values be under 10.. :) thanks.

```
"10 Jan 2018, 09:08"
"10 Jan 2018, 13:08"
```

Comment: What do you mean by **add... I don't want just insert '0' into time data :) thanks.** here ? Can you explain please.

Comment: @SagarGautam, hi, look at there! what is different 9:08 and 09:08 :)

Comment: Oh I've just noticed, let me see

Comment: So, you just want to display time like hour value without leading zeros am I right ?

Comment: @SagarGautam, yes

Comment: I think your code seems correct since `G` refers hours without leading zero. It's difficult to identify the problem. Other might help you.

Comment: @Magnetic have you check the answer is it working for you?

Comment: @PrateikDarji, yes thank you for your answer, but it didn't show as my goal.   I'm using this code to make pdf file, so if data row has over 1000, then it should need more time to make it. thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way using css but with the trick you can do that just check the below code

```
@php  
    $exdate = explode(",", $job->created_at->format('d M Y, G:i'));
    $time = (strlen($exdate[1]<=4))? $exdate[0]." &nbsp;&nbsp;".$exdate[1] : $job->created_at->format('d M Y, G:i');
@endphp    
<td>{!! $time !!}</td>
<td>{!! $time !!}</td>
```